# How to make text glow programmatically (via code, not xml) in android?

Tags: android, textview, android-xml, glow

I want to know how to make my text glow in android, I know how to do via xml with some attributes, like this:

```
android:shadowColor="#6A8B00"
android:shadowDx="3"
android:shadowDy="3"
android:shadowRadius="10"
android:text="@string/glowText"
android:textColor="#E15529"
android:textSize="30sp"
```

but I want to do via code, then I can control better and make glow more or less in different situations.
Maybe has something like view.setGlow?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `setShadowLayer (float radius, float dx, float dy, int color)` on your textview. For example:

```
textView.setShadowLayer(30, 0, 0, Color.RED);
```

Found in the TextView [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setShadowLayer(float,%20float,%20float,%20int))